# Values won't store

Tags: python

I've had this problem for a while, where some of my values will just refuse to store. It's most likely because of a rule which I am breaking somewhere, but after searching the Internet for *quite* some time and I can't find the problem.

Code:

```
#TO SET#

def min_count_set():
  stancount = int(input("How many standard miners do you wish to start with? "))
  if (stancount > 10000 or stancount < 0):
    print("\n Please enter a valid number to start with. \n \n")
    min_count_set()
  else:
    advcount= int(input("How many advanced miners do you wish to start with? "))
  if (advcount > 10000 or advcount < 0):
    print("\n Please enter a valid number to start with. \n \n")
    min_count_set()
  else:
    ultrcount = int(input("How many ultra miners do you wish to start with? "))
  if (ultrcount > 10000 or ultrcount < 0):
    print("\n Please enter a valid number to start with. \n \n")
    min_count_set()
  else:
    print("\n Returning you to the setup menu \n \n")
  set_mining_values()

#TO PRINT#
def view_mining_values():
  print("\n Printing all of the variables now.")
  print("\n Number of standard miners starting with: ")
  print(stancount)
  print("\n Number of advanced miners starting with: ")
  print(advcount)
  print("\n Number of ultra miners starting with: ")
  print(ultrcount)
```

The error I receive is:

```
NameError: name 'stancount' is not defined
```

I previously tried giving the variable `stancount` a number and then run it through the input, but then it would just relay the number I gave it before the input.

Comment: you are trying to access stancount variable  outside the scope of function

Comment: lot of stuff bad here, first you dont return anything within the function, nor capture it from the recursive call, `advcount` and `ultrcount` are not shared between the calls, each call is a completly separate scope

Comment: Those variables are defined in another function, also show us the definition of set_mining_values

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439752/python-local-vs-global-variables

Comment: define `stancount` outside the scope of any functions, then use the functions to modify the value of `stancount`

Comment: Suggest you read the answers to the question [_Short Description of Scoping Rules_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules).

Comment: Hi tom, because you accepted my answer can you please give it an upvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to declare the variable outside the functions and modify them inside the functions because variables are local to where they are defined, because you are defining `stancount` inside a function it is then essentially "deleted" when you leave the function: I recommend something similar to this;

```
def min_count_set():
  stancount = int(input("How many standard miners do you wish to start with? "))
  #do stuff
  set_mining_values()
  return stancount


def view_mining_values(stancount):
  print("\n Printing all of the variables now.")
  print("\n Number of standard miners starting with: ")
  print(stancount)
  #do more stuff

stancount=min_count_set()
```

this will set `stancount` to the value you set in the function and also allow you to print it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The `stancount` variable is out of scope when you try to print it.

You could pass it into the `print_mining_values()` function as an argument and print it that way,

So `print_mining_values()` would become:

```
def view_mining_values(sCount, aCount, uCount):
    print("\n Printing all of the variables now.")
    print("\n Number of standard miners starting with: ")
    print(sCount)
    print("\n Number of advanced miners starting with: ") 
    print(aCount) 
    print("\n Number of ultra miners starting with: ")
    print(uCount)
```

and your `min_count_set()` function would become:

```
def min_count_set():
    stancount = int(input("How many standard miners do you wish to start with? "))
    if (stancount > 10000 or stancount < 0):
        print("\n Please enter a valid number to start with. \n \n")
        min_count_set()
    else:
        advcount= int(input("How many advanced miners do you wish to start with? "))
    if (advcount > 10000 or advcount < 0):
        print("\n Please enter a valid number to start with. \n \n")
        min_count_set()
    else:
        ultrcount = int(input("How many ultra miners do you wish to start with? "))
    if (ultrcount > 10000 or ultrcount < 0):
        print("\n Please enter a valid number to start with. \n \n")
        min_count_set()
    else:
        print("\n Returning you to the setup menu \n \n")
    set_mining_values(stancount, advcount, ultrcount)
```

Notice the variables are now passed into your printing function.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `stancount` as a global variable like:

```
def min_count_set():
    global stancount
```

Comment: but then he cant use `stancount` in local scope to do unsaved changes to the variable

Comment: True (sorry) but I thought he wanted to access this local variable in other places (hence my answer).