# How to functionalize code that drops rows of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns that sometimes have nan values. I know that I could remove these en masse using pandas own `dropna` function but I wanted to write my own function in this case that I can then individually call on each column so I wrote:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
def remove_nans_from_column(column_name):
    data = data[~data[column_name].isna()]
remove_nans_from_column('bmi')
```

But running this produces this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3be0ddcb71ff> in <module>()
----> 1 remove_nans_from_column('bmi')

<ipython-input-26-911d33fb618e> in remove_nans_from_column(column_name)
      1 def remove_nans_from_column(column_name):
----> 2     data = data[~data[column_name].isna()]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I understand that the variable data is not defined inside the function but it should be able to get it from the rest of the code.

```
data = data[~data['bmi'].isna()]
```

works when it is not inside a function so why does it not work in a function?

I am more curious about the reason for this error here rather than how to fix it which I can already do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439752/python-local-vs-global-variables

Comment: What about using the built-in `dropna()` method instead?

Comment: @Chris thanks for the link. I already know what variable scopes are when I posted the question. if i understand correctly from the link you sent, this answer is that python gets confused when you modify a variable from the larger scope within a function and this should be avoided?

Comment: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)