# Explain for symbol, symbol_count in symbols.items():

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

I don't understand this line:

```
for symbol, symbol_count in symbols.items():
```

`symbol` has never been a variable, is it from the variable `symbol_count`? If so, how does the code know what `symbol` is if it has not been a variable or defined?

```
symbol_count = {
  "A": 2,
  "B": 4,
  "C": 6,
  "D": 8
}

def get_slot_machine_spin(rows, cols, symbols):
  all_symbols = []
  for symbol, symbol_count in symbols.items():
    for _ in range(symbol_count):
      all_symbols.append(symbol)
```

Comment: I suggest reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html , as well as the other docs over the `.items()` function of dict types

Comment: [What is a debugger, and how can it help me solve problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: As a complement to the previous, this question is (also) ripe for the [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) technique.  Explain to your duck the exact meaning of each line of code ... using the official Python documentation to help you work it out.  For example, `symbol_count` is a `dict` so lookup what `items()` is for a `dict`.  Likewise for `append` and `range`.

Comment: (Note that the RDD technique works by you explaining things to your duck, not the other way around.  We don't want to be your duck.)

Comment: My code does none of these:                                                                                     
When I run my program, it does not produce the output I expect for the input I gave it.
When I run my program, it crashes and gives me a stack trace. I have examined the stack trace, but I still do not know the cause of the problem because the stack trace does not provide me with enough information.
When I run my program, it crashes because of a segmentation fault (SEGV). I don't need a debugger I need a person to help me understand this one line. @EJoshuaS

Comment: The edit makes this question much clearer and more focused. I voted to reopen because the question is now answerable (although the rude commentary made it rather tempting not to).

Comment: Yes, the edited question is quite good - but it's also a duplicate.

Comment: The loop unpacks the key and value into symbol and symbol_count respectively. symbol will take the value of each key of the symbols dictionary and symbol_count will take the value of the count of each symbol. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Understanding for loops in Python was not the issue. I had an issue understanding one line. You obviously have something against new programmers. You've done everything you can to stop me from receiving help on this platform @tripleee
  . I responded to the "rude commentary" from Stephen C nothing more. If you want people just to review the docs then re-direct this site to the docs. I didn't need a debugger. I needed some simple help. That's obviously not possible here. Fortunately I found the help I needed elsewhere, thank you to the people that tried to help I appreciate it.

Comment: I answered your question, and you think I hold a personal grudge somehow? That's new. If you have a different problem which you didn't explain in the question, how are we supposed to be able to help with that?

Comment: I explained my issue and you wanted me to update my question, so I did. Then you banned me from asking questions for 7 days because I updated the question you wanted me to update. Then you closed the question stating that it has already been associated with a similar question. It wasn't the same at all. By the time you answered my question you had pushed me to find my answer elsewhere, ChatGPT answered it. When I stated that you deleted the comment. People make snarky comments to new people here and they do it intentionally. You obviously don't want us here. All this for such a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement *creates* variables.

```
for variable (, othervar, ....) in expression:
```

In this case, the `expression` is something which returns pairs of values (so basically, a 2-tuple) and so `for` can declare two variables and have them receive one value each, similarly to how you can say

```
symbol, symbol_count = "stack overflow", 42
```

In some more detail, `symbols` in this case is apparently a `dict` variable, and [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict.items) loops over the keys and returns one key and its value in each iteration.

Quick demo:

```
>>> symbols = {"foo": 17, "bar": 42, "baz": 1427}
>>> for symbol, symbol_count in symbols.items():
...   print("symbol:", symbol)
...   print("count:", symbol_count)
...
symbol: foo
count: 17
symbol: bar
count: 42
symbol: baz
count: 1427
```

Because the `for` loop creates a new variable named `symbol_count`, it is now a local variable which shadows the global dict with the same name; the two are distinct and unrelated, other than in that they share the same name in two separate symbol tables. Perhaps also read up on [global vs local scope in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439752/python-local-vs-global-variables)

Comment: I found a duplicate for the question in my saves. Would you mind migrating the answer? The specific sticking point of "what if `symbol` didn't exist before?" isn't well covered there, but I think *that* part is clearly the same question. Although I'm not sure whether the bit about the unpacking syntax (`symbol, symbol_count`) is focused enough. The OP for the other question didn't ask about it. But as I understood it, the question either way is *primarily* about the `for` loop construct itself.

Comment: The red-herring of the shadowed `symbol_count` is definitely out of focus, however.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry, I can't really see which aspect of this you want migrated. Perhaps you can copy/paste this and use it as the basis for a new answer for the other question; feel free. Also, maybe ping me so I can delete this then.