# Why can Python functions sometimes access variables outside their scope?

Tags: python, function, scope

I have noticed a behavior of Python functions that I cannot fit into my naive understanding of local vs. global scope.
For example, this

```
x = 1
y = 1
def f():
    print(x+y)
f()
```

appears to be valid Python code, as it does not produce an error message and the function is executed. But it seems to break the rules, since `x` and `y` are neither global variables nor are they arguments to `f()` nor are they defined within the local scope of `f()`, still `f()` can access those variables. Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: A variable which is defined in the main body of a file is called a global variable.

Comment: As long as there is no assignment to a variable inside a function and its not a function argument, any variable is assumed to be global. See e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360229/python-why-is-global-needed-only-on-assignment-and-not-on-reads

Comment: You might want to read about the LEGB rule.

Comment: To add to the other good comments explaining this, directly from the Python docs FAQs (https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python): "In Python, variables that are only _referenced_ inside a function are implicitly global."