# How do i assign a variable to a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

I am very new to Python and I'm trying to make a function so that when I call it, it assigns something to a variable. I don't know how to explain it better but this is what i got now:

```
again = '0'
def printa():
    print(again)
def f1():
    again = '1'
def f2():
    again = '2'
x = input()
x = str(x)
if x == '8':
    f1()
elif x == '9':
    f2()
printa()
```

My objective is that when I write 8 the output is 1 and when I write 9 the output is 2; and right now the output is always 0. I know I could just write `if x == 8 print 1` but I need to use functions

Comment: "I need to use functions" Is this some exercise you need to solve? If yes, adding the precise requirements might help.

Comment: Just to be clear: You want ``again = '1'`` inside ``f1`` to change the value of the *global* variable ``again``?

Comment: I'm making a GUI for a rock paper scissors game that I made, and I'm learning to use tkinter for that (I just started to learn today so I dont know much), and I need that when a press a button on the screen it assign a value to a variable, and using the global keyword that gesuchter and roman suggested I got it working

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to modify the variable `again` inside of `f1()` and `f2()` you would have to use the (mostly unrecommended) `global` keyword. You have to do this, because `again` is out of scope for the functions ([Python: Why is global needed only on assignment and not on reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360229/python-why-is-global-needed-only-on-assignment-and-not-on-reads)).

```py
again = '0'

def printa():
    print(again)
    
def f1():
    global again
    again = '1'
    
def f2():
    global again
    again = '2'
    
x = input()
if x == '8':
    f1()
elif x == '9':
    f2()
    
printa()
```

Notice that you do not need to convert `x` to a string since `input()` will do this automatically.

However, a better approach would be to use a function which takes an argument:

````py
def printa(arg):
    if arg == '8':
        print('1')
    elif arg == '9':
        print('2')
    else:
        print(arg)
    
x = input()
printa(x)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Set `again` variable as `global` if you want to change global var value from function

```
def f1():
    global again
    again = '1'
def f2():
    global again
    again = '2'
```

But may be it would be better to change logic

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
def func():
  x = str(input())
  if x == '9':
    return '1'
  elif x == '8':
    return '2'
  else:
    print("'9' or '8' not entered")


func() # To call the function
```