# Function accesses global variable depending on useage in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables, global

I only just came across this and it's managed to confuse me. I tried to use the same idea as `Function2` but it didn't work, what confused me was it was managing to access other global variables even though I hadn't used `global` at all.
It seems it depends on how you use the variable which just doesn't seem right to me.
I understand all I need to do is `global number` in `Function2` but why is it that this doesn't work?

```
number = 5

def Function1():
    temp = number
    print(temp)

def Function2():
    number += 1
    print(number)
    
def Function3():
    print(number)
    
Function1() # >>>  5

Function2() #      line 8, in Function2
            #      number += 1
            #      UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment

Function3() # >>>  5
```

`Function1` and `Function3` work as I expect whereas `Function2` does not.

I also tried replacing the `number += 1` with `number = number + 1` but same error occured.

- Python version 3.9.13

Comment: It may not be intuitive, but the `global` keyword is only needed to modify a global variable versus access it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360229/python-why-is-global-needed-only-on-assignment-and-not-on-reads

Comment: You **never** need `global` to *merely access* a global variable, you need `global` to *assign* to a local variable. Any assignment to a variable in a function makes the compiler mark it as *local* by default. Hence, if you try to access that variable before it is defined, you get an UnboundLocal error. This is the same as just doing `x += 1` when `x` has no value (in the global scope, this would raise a NameError)